# Estimable Function Definition: Why $\forall \beta?$

Tags: self-study, linear-model, gauss-markov-theorem

I am reading *Linear Models with R, 2nd Ed.,* by Julian J. Faraway, and on page 22, section 2.8 on the Gauss-Markov Theorem, he defines an *estimable linear combination* as follows:

> A linear combination of the parameters $\psi=c^T\beta$ is estimable if and only if there exists a linear combination $a^Ty$ such that:
> $$Ea^Ty=c^T\beta\qquad \forall\beta.$$

Note that the author uses a plain $E$ for expectation.

Now I understand [why we need this definition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302015/what-is-the-point-of-introducing-the-concept-of-estimable-function), but I am hung up on those last two symbols: $\forall\beta.$ Why are those included in the definition? I've looked around a bit, and other authors do the same thing. It looks sloppy to me, though, because haven't we already said which particular $\beta$ we're talking about by writing $\psi=c^T\beta?$

Another way of looking at it is that order matters in quantifiers. If I say $(\forall\varepsilon)(\exists\delta)$ such that..., it's **very different** from saying $(\exists\delta)(\forall\varepsilon)$ such that...

A third way of looking at it is this: once you find a linear combination $a^Ty$ that works for $\psi=c^T\beta,$ if you were to change $\beta$ (because, apparently, we can!), how could you possibly still have $Ea^Ty=c^T\beta?$

Why isn't it phrased this way (which makes MUCH more sense to me):

> A linear combination of the parameters $\psi=c^T\beta$ is estimable if and only if, for every $\beta,$ there exists a linear combination $a^Ty$ such that $E(a^Ty)=c^T\beta.$

A little further on, in the proof of the Gauss-Markov Theorem, the author reasons from $a^TX\beta=c^T\beta\quad\forall\beta$ to $a^TX=c^T,$ which would not necessarily be true if $\beta$ is a particular choice as opposed to arbitrary. So that would be an argument in favor of the $\forall\beta$ being tacked on at the end like that. Maybe if you could give me a simple example where we vary the $\beta$ but $Ea^Ty$ still equals $c^T\beta?$

Comment: Are you perhaps misunderstanding the quantifiers?  The "last two symbols $\forall\beta$" are read *for all $\beta$" which is the same thing as "for every $\beta.$"  In the context, it is clear that $\beta$ is an element of a given vector space, so the shorthand isn't that sloppy.

Comment: It's entirely possible I'm misunderstanding the quantifiers! I certainly understand that $\forall\beta$ means "for all $\beta$" or "for every $\beta$". However, my question is about whether this definition is talking about a *particular* $\beta$ or *arbitary* $\beta$'s. $\psi=c^T\beta$ appears to be talking about a particular beta, since that equation is quoted before the condition. But the symbols $\forall\beta$ at the end appear to be talking about arbitrary $\beta$'s, since that's what meant by the universal quantifier. How does knowing the vector space $\beta$ lives in clear this up?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification at the end, particularly. That clears it up for me: the $\forall\beta$ is supposed to come first. If you have mixed quantifiers (both universal and existential), then the order definitely matters. Your question in your comment illustrates precisely why it matters. If your quantifiers are all of the same type, then order does not matter. See this question on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491783/intuitive-reason-that-quantifier-order-matters for a very nice intuitive explanation for why order matters.

Comment: Yes, order matters: but I deleted my comment because I believe it was incorrect.

Comment: Oh, ok. So what are you thinking now? I still have a confusion with the rest of the proof. In matrix land, $AB=0$ does not necessarily imply that $A=0$ or $B=0.$ Matrices are not an integral domain in general. Now if $AB=0$ for all $B,$ then I think you can make the case that $A=0.$ But I'm not sure that reasoning is valid in this circumstance, because what the proof is saying is: choose your $\beta,$ then choose your $a^Ty$ so that $Ea^Ty=c^T\beta.$ Then, if you please, $a^TX\beta=c^T\beta$ implies $a^Tx=c^T.$ Not sure that follows.

Answer (score 2):

Upon reflecting more about this in comments, I have come to see how poor this construction is.  About the only way to resolve the issue is to determine what "estimable" is really intended to mean.

Rather than go into all the ramifications, I intend only to offer a clear restatement.  The correct language to use is that of *dual vector spaces.*  The dual of any vector space $V$ is the space of all linear functions from $V$ into its ground field, written $V^{*}.$  These are called "forms."

When $V$ is finite-dimensional, $V^{*}$ consists of all functions of the form $x\to c^\prime x$ for $c\in V.$  In other words, *left multiplication by vector transposes is just one particular way of naming (representing) a form.*  But this does permit us to think of vectors as *columns* and forms as *rows.*

In the setting, $y$ is a random variable with values in the vector space $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ and the parameters $\beta$ are considered elements of the vector space $W=\mathbb{R}^k.$  Both are (column) vectors.

Before going on, let me remark that $\beta$ parameterizes a set of models.  It helps to think of this set very abstractly: that is, rather than considering $\beta$ to be an array of numbers, think of it as *naming a model* that is under consideration as an explanation of the data.  Now the underlying idea begins to gel: a function defined on the set of models is a *property.*  That is, the forms in $W^{*}$ are particular kinds of *scalar* properties of the models--namely, linear properties.

The models determine the distributions of the random variables $y.$  Thus, to be fully explicit, we ought to write $y$ as $y_\beta= (y_{1\beta}, y_{2\beta}, \ldots, y_{n\beta}).$

Consider a form $a\in V^*.$  Composing it with $y$ yields a scalar-valued random variable.  Thus, for any model represented by $\beta\in W,$ $E[a(y_\beta)]$ is a *property* of that model.

This construction has defined a map $f$ from $V^{*}$ into $W^{*}:$ the expectation of the form $a$ (composed with $y_\beta$) happens to be a *linear* property of $\beta,$ whence it is in $W^{*}.$  That is, $f(a):W \to \mathbb R$ is given by

$$(f(a))(\beta) = E[a(y_\beta)].$$

Now, despite whatever qualms one might have about the level of abstraction, the relationship explicitly references the key objects $a$ and $\beta$ on both sides!

> The *estimable* properties are the image of $f:$ namely, the subspace $f(V^{*})\subset W^{*}.$

If you still prefer, you can write out the definition of the image along with the definition of $f.$

> A form $c\in W^{*}$ is *estimable* if and only if there exists a form $a \in V^{*}$ for which $E[a(y_\beta)] = c(\beta).$

Translation into more meaningful language:

> *Estimable* properties of a linear model are those that arise as expectations of linear combinations of the responses.

We have arrived at a good place, because we have been able to describe a concept *without relying on a particular form of mathematical representation of the objects involved.*  There is no reference to column or row vectors anywhere in this description.

#### Concrete example

Model three observations $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3=V$ as *iid* draws from a Normal$(\beta_1+\beta_2, 1)$ distribution.  Although the space of *models* is one-dimensional (corresponding to the common mean $\beta_1+\beta_2$), the parameters $\beta_i$ are vectors in $W=\mathbb{R}^2.$

The forms $a\in V^{*} = \mathbb{R}^{3*}$ are all functions that can be expressed as

$$a(x_1,x_2,x_3)=a_1x_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3$$

for three numbers $a_i.$  Compute expectations, using the fact that the expectation of each of the $y_{i\beta}$ is the expectation of a Normal$(\beta_1+\beta_2,1)$ variable, equal to $\beta_1+\beta_2:$

$$E[a(y_\beta)] = E[a_1y_{1\beta} + a_2 y_{2\beta} + a_3 y_{3\beta}] = a_1(\beta_1+\beta_2) + a_2(\beta_1+\beta_2) + a_3(\beta_1+\beta_2).$$

This is the map

$$\mathbb{R}^2 \ni (\beta_1, \beta_2) \to (a_1+a_2+a_3)(\beta_1+\beta_2),$$

considered as an element of $W^* = \mathbb{R}^{2*}.$  (As a row vector, it is $(1,1)$ multiplied by $a_1+a_2+a_3.$)  The set of all such maps is the subspace of forms

$$(\beta_1,\beta_2) \to A(\beta_1 + \beta_2)$$

for $A\in \mathbb R,$ generated by the form represented by $(1,1).$  It is a strict subspace, because it is (obviously) just one-dimensional.  For instance, the map $(\beta_1,\beta_2) \to \beta_1,$ represented by the row vector $(1,0),$ is not in this subspace -- and therefore, by definition, is not estimable.

For *this parameterization of this model,* we would say "only multiples of the sum of the two parameters are estimable -- no other functions of the parameters are estimable."

#### Resolution

How to interpret the quantifiers in the original quotation?  It should now be evident that the form $a$ is intended to work for all $\beta:$ it cannot vary with $\beta.$

Equivalently, the quotation refers to two forms, $\beta\to E[a^\prime y]$ and $\beta\to c^\prime \beta.$  As such the symbol "$\beta$" serves only as a placeholder for an arbitrary element of the common domain $W$ of those forms. Since the authors saw no problem not mentioning $\beta$ on the left hand side, they could with equal accuracy--and perhaps better clarity--simply write "$E[a^\prime y]=c^\prime,$" assuming both sides are understood as *functions defined on $W.$*

Comment: Wow, that's a lot! I've read your answer at least three times, now, and I may be starting to understand a small portion of it. It sounds to me like one important takeaway is that $y$ and $\beta$ are logically related, and the $a$ and $c$ are logically related. Is that a fair statement?

Comment: A thought: the idea of an estimable linear combination is arising in the context of proving the Gauss-Markov theorem, which is concerned with $\beta$ as the OLS estimator. Could we restrict our attention to $\beta=\hat\beta$ as the OLS estimator, so that $\beta=\beta(y,X)?$

Comment: At the end: did you mean $E[a']=c'?$ How are both sides functions defined on $W?$

Comment: How about this: a form $c$ is estimable if and only if, for every model $\beta$ and response $y=X\beta,$ there exists a form $a$ such that $E(a^Ty)=c^T\beta?$

Comment: Oh, no, that doesn't work. How about this: a form $c$ is estimable if and only if there exists a form $a$ such that for every model $\beta$ and response $y=X\beta,$ we have $E\!\left(a^Ty\right)=c^T\beta?$